# How to merge two 4-dims arrays by the 3th dim

Tags: julia

That is, merge A whose size is [2,3,4,5] and B whose size is [2,3,6,5], to C whose size is [2,3,10,5].

I know how to do it. But how to complete it efficiently for both me and the machine.

I have tried following code but it did not work.

```
permutedims([permutedims(A,[1,2,4,3]) permutedims(B,[1,2,4,3])],[1,2,4,3])
```

Comment: Try `cat`. As in `cat(A, B, dims=3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`cat`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/arrays/#Base.cat) (concatenate) function for this. It takes a keyword argument `dims` which allows you to specify the dimension along which you'd like to concatenate.

```
julia> A = rand(2,3,4,5);

julia> B = rand(2,3,6,5);

julia> C = cat(A, B, dims=3);

julia> size(C)
(2, 3, 10, 5)
```

You can find out more about the `cat` function by typing `?cat` into the Julia REPL.